# Polynomial kernel expansion

Tags: symbolic, polynomials, series-expansion

I am trying to calculate the [polynomial kernel expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_kernel) using *Mathematica*. I have tried the `Expand` and `Simplify` functions with no success.

I do:

```
(Sum[Subscript[x, i] * Subscript[y, i], {i, n}] + c)^2 // Expand
```

And I get (which seems correct):

$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i + c\right)^2 =  c^2 + 2c\sum_i^n x_iy_i +\left(\sum_i^n x_iy_i\right)^2
$$

I try to expand the last part by doing:

```
Sum[Subscript[x, i] * Subscript[y, i], {i, n}]^2 // Expand
```

But again I get the same form:

$$
\left(\sum_i^n x_iy_i\right)^2
$$

I would like to get something closer to:

$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i\right)^2 = 
\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i^2\right) \left(y_i^2 \right) + 
\sum_{i=2}^n \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \left( \sqrt{2} x_i x_j \right) 
                              \left( \sqrt{2} y_i y_j \right) 
$$

**Any ideas on how to approach this?**

Comment: In the first instance, you are expanding (a + c)^2, which Mathematica handles routinely, even if `a` is a `Sum`.  In the second, you are asking Mathematica to restructure the `Sum` itself, which it does not do routinely.

Comment: To follow up on @bbgodfrey's comment: in short, Mathematica won't do that for you. You will have to implement your own transformation rule based on the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into transformation rules.